# UWooCommerce - add cart discount programmatically?

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, bulk

I need to develop a plugin that applies a discount to the cart if x number of products have been purchased. Could someone point me in the direction of the code/API I need to use.

Can find nothing from https://docs.woothemes.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-codex/ and do not fancy paying $100+ for the official bulk discount plugin just to get some simple functionality like this.

I have found that [WooCommerce's get_total_discount() function](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#2157-2169) applies the `woocommerce_cart_total_discount` filter, but I don't seem to be able to successfully tap into that filter...

```
function mwe_calculate_discount( $total_discount, $cart ) {

    //global $woocommerce;
    $num_products_required_for_discount = 4;

    echo "<!-- Discount? -->";

    $number_products = $cart->cart_contents_count;
    if ($number_products >= $num_products_required_for_discount) {

        echo "<!-- QUALIFIES FOR DISCOUNT! -->";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_products; $i++) {

            // Get the reduced price of the product - TODO

            // Calculate $product_discount
            $product_discount = 11.11; // TODO

            // Add $product_discount to the $total_discount
            $total_discount += $product_discount;
        }

        echo "<!-- Total discount: $total_discount -->";

    }
    else {

        echo "<!-- NO DISCOUNT -->";

    }

    return $total_discount;

}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_total_discount', 'mwe_calculate_discount', 10, 2);
```

...any idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I have found the article about WooCommerce discount cart which describe how to get discount on total sales, orders, shipping cost and sales per item
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/woocommerce-discount-cart/

Answer (score 3):

I haven't applied any discounts like that before, but have done it with 'fees' a lot.

Adding a fee is quite easy:

```
function custom_wc_add_fee() {
    WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Fee', -10 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_wc_add_fee' );
```

(or if you want a plugin solution, I created this plugin: https://aceplugins.com/plugin/woocommerce-advanced-fees/)

Comment: Great , It's working .. :)

Comment: this works, but woocommerce discourages negative fees. For a time they had blocked them, but too many people complained and the reverted back: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13224

Comment: Yes, Woo indeed shortly discouraged that (even removed) it and put back shortly after. At the time they were indicating a new Discounts API, but that was revised again and changed to officially supporting negative fees as per; https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/16528

Comment: Just to let you know, negative fees will interfere with totals if some of your products have tax, and others dont.